# Electron: Include binary dependency with Webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, binary, electron

I'm trying to use Webpack in my electron project to bundle the Typescript code in my main process (the renderer is an Angular project managed with the CLI).

But in my main process I have a dependency on [registry-js](https://github.com/desktop/registry-js):

```
import { enumerateValues, HKEY } from "registry-js";
```

Registry-js is built to a `.node-binary`. So my question is how I can include that in my bundle? Currently my `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./main.ts",
  target: "electron-main",
  output: {
    path: "./dist-main",
    filename: "main.bundle.js",
  },
  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
    alias: {
      "registry-js": path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/registry-js/build/Release/registry.node"),
    }
  }
};
```

When I start my application I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' of undefined`

What can I do to include the binary in my Webpack build to be able to run my application in dev mode and as production build?

Answer (score 2):

Webpack cannot bundle native addon modules. You should use appropriate loader like node-loader or node-addon-loader and copy binaries when create package.

Comment: Can you show me how? I've tried but not managed to understand how to use node-loader.